# Drag only inside a Parent element with React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-grid-layout

I am trying to make a draggable element only inside his parent, not in all the screen of the browser.
My problem is that I don't know how to do with React and styled components.
The situation is that at this moment is draggable, but I can move in all the website (to make the drag and drop I am using 'react-grid-layout' as library)
is there a css property to make impossible to move the items outside his parent? It should be with JS?
This is my code:

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(allPosts);

  const layout = {
    lg: [
      { i: '1', x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 4 },
      { i: '2', x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 4 },
      { i: '3', x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 4 },
      { i: '4', x: 1, y: 1, w: 1, h: 4 },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <GridContainer
      className='layout'
      isDraggable
      layouts={layout}
      rowHeight={40}
      cols={{ lg: 4 }}
      margin={[30, 30]}
    >
      {posts.map(post => (
        <Container key={post.id}>
          <InformationBox title={post.title} description={post.description} type={post.type} />
        </Container>
      ))}
    </GridContainer>
  );
};
```

[THAT SHOULD NOT BE POSSIBLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGbGw.png)

[IT SHOULD BE LIKE THAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Lis.png)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting isBounded to true on the ReactGridLayout like this:

````
<ReactGridLayout
          ...
          isBounded={true}
          .../>```
````